# How to pick up data from json objects in python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pick `Instances` in the json objects data which looks like this

`[{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-0ceecbb0f30a902a6', 'InstanceId': 'i-xxxxx', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'xxxx', 'LaunchTime': {'$date': '2022-12-17T13:07:54Z'}, 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'us-west-2b', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-zxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 'xxxxx', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIpAddress': 'xxxxxx', 'State': {'Code': 16, 'Name': 'running'}, 'StateTransitionReason': '', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-xxxxx', 'VpcId': 'vpc-xxxxx', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': {'$date': '2022-12-17T13:07:55Z'}, 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxx'}}], 'ClientToken': '529fc1ac-bf64-4804-b0b8-7c7778ace68c', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Association': {'IpOwnerId': 'amazon', 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-35-86-111-31.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIp': 'xxxxx'}, 'Attachment': {'AttachTime': {'$date': '2022-12-17T13:07:54Z'}, 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-0cac7d4af20664b23', 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached', 'NetworkCardIndex': 0}, 'Description': '', 'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-5', 'GroupId': 'sg-xxxxx'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': 'xxxxx', 'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-xxxxx', 'OwnerId': 'xxxx', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-xxxxx.us-west-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 'xxx.xxx.xxx', 'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Association': {'IpOwnerId': 'amazon', 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIp': 'xxx.xxx.xxx'}, 'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-187.us-west-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 'xxx.xxx.xxx'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-xxxxxxx', 'VpcId': 'vpc-0b09cd4sedxxx', 'InterfaceType': 'interface'}], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-5', 'GroupId': 'sg-0a0d1c79d8076660e'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'MainServers'}], 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}, 'CapacityReservationSpecification': {'CapacityReservationPreference': 'open'}, 'HibernationOptions': {'Configured': False}, 'MetadataOptions': {'State': 'applied', 'HttpTokens': 'optional', 'HttpPutResponseHopLimit': 1, 'HttpEndpoint': 'enabled', 'HttpProtocolIpv6': 'disabled', 'InstanceMetadataTags': 'disabled'}, 'EnclaveOptions': {'Enabled': False}, 'PlatformDetails': 'Linux/UNIX', 'UsageOperation': 'RunInstances', 'UsageOperationUpdateTime': {'$date': '2022-12-17T13:07:54Z'}, 'PrivateDnsNameOptions': {'HostnameType': 'ip-name', 'EnableResourceNameDnsARecord': True, 'EnableResourceNameDnsAAAARecord': False}, 'MaintenanceOptions': {'AutoRecovery': 'default'}}], 'OwnerId': '76979cfxdsss11', 'ReservationId': 'r-xxxxx'}]`

I tired loading data and doing

```
   resp = json.loads(jsonfile)
   reqData= resp['Instances']
```

But getting error

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Is there any way I can fix this and get the data? Help will be extremely appriciated.

Comment: seems `resp` is a list, not a dict. You can try `resp[0]["instances"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrapped inside a list. So simply do:

```py
print(lst[0]["Instances"])
```

Answer (score 1):

To select only the instances from the data, you can use the json.loads function to parse the JSON data and extract the Instances field as a list.

```
import json

# Parse the JSON data
data = json.loads(json_data)

# Extract the instances
instances = data['Instances']
```

###### You can then iterate over the data with something like this

```
for instance in instances:
    instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
    instance_type = instance['InstanceType']
    launch_time = instance['LaunchTime']
```